# Android: make a search recent history on autocompletetextview

Tags: android, android-sqlite, autocompletetextview

I'm making an autoCompleteTextView for searching and I want to save on the disk when user type a word and press search the word so the next time he will type the same word to show a suggestion with the previous most recents typed words. I believe I have to make it with a sql database but I'm not familiar with databases since I'm new and I don't know how to add the words on the sql with chronological order. Any other suggestion or how to make the database?

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: I know how to make a simple database with sqlLite but I don't know how to add things with chronological sort so when I can take the most recent first.

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html  see 1.2 Date and Time Datatype